# How do we prove that $\tan(x + \frac{\pi}{3}) = \cot(-x +\frac{\pi}{6})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question about the cofunction formula.  Is this the right formula to simplify?

The book says $tan(x + \frac{\pi}{3}) = cot(-x +\frac{\pi}{6})$

I used the cofunction formula $cot=tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}) = cot(\frac{\pi}{6})$. Cot is the reciprocal function of tan and to reflect the cot across the y axis x has to be-x.  I was wondering about how to show proof of the reciprocal relationship between cot and tan?  I don’t really feel like I do that.

Comment: Since cot is a cofunction for tan, $\tan (x+\pi/3)=\cot(\pi/2-(x+\pi/3))=\cot (\pi/6-x)$

Comment: Alternative approach:  $$\tan(a \pm b) = \frac{\tan(a) \pm \tan(b)}{1 \mp \tan(a)\tan(b)}$$ and $$\cot(a \pm b) = \frac{\cot(a)\cot(b) \mp 1}{\cot(a) \mp \cot(b)}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach consists in proceeding as follows:

\begin{align*}
\tan\left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) & = \frac{\sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\cos\left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)}\\\\
& = \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)}\\\\
& = \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - x\right)}\\\\
& = \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - x\right)
\end{align*}

In general, based on the same procedure as before, the next identity holds:
\begin{align*}
\tan(\alpha) = \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right)
\end{align*}

whenever the argument is well defined.

Hopefully this helps !